# How to use stuff on entire columns of the table:

Tags: sql-server, vba, mssql-jdbc

I  executed the below query and it executed well :-

```
SELECT table2id, stuff((select CHAR(13) + table1name  from table1 where table1id=table2.table2id FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
, 1, 1, '')
 from table2 where table2id=117 group by id;
```

But when I am using count(*) , like in below query :-

```
SELECT table2id, stuff((select CHAR(13) + count(*)  from table1 where table1id=table2.table2id FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
, 1, 1, '')
 from table2 where table2id=117 group by id;
```

I am getting the below error:

```
 Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '
' to data type int.
```

Now how can I stuff all the columns  in table1 ? could anyone help !

I want my result like below:-

```
table2id  |  table1name  |  table1id  | table1color
------------------------------------------------------
  117     |  jon, jack   |   117,117  | blue,red
```

( I am adding my sample data for `table1` and `table2`) :-

table1:

```
table1id | table1name | table1color | table1city | table1animal |...(I 
   have 25 columns like this !)
--------------------------------------------------------------   
117      | jon        | blue        | city1      | animal1       

117      | jack       | red         | city2      | animal2
```

table2:

```
table2id | table2uniqueid
-------------------------
117      | asbn6383hhh3j3837
118      | kf9s8sujfu6df5d7j
```

Comment: Add sample data we will give exact result

Comment: implement same stuff for multiple columns

Comment: @mohan111, I have 25 columns, now how can I implement the same stuff on each column?  The query becomes very lengthy !!

Comment: @Srini131, I have added sample data of table1 and table2 above, kindly check and advise me (any clarification.) ThankYou !

Comment: @JackCarothers i had updated my code by using dynamic sql try this ,get back to me once you get the result

Comment: @Srini131  Thanks a lot for your effort, thankyou, I will try that and update.

Comment: @JackCarothers Hi Just add your Table names in the place of Table1 And Table2

Comment: @JackCarothers Hi what's up is my code helpful to you ?

Comment: @Srini131, I am sure your code works fine, but I have found another way to solve my problem (not from sql, but from code behind in vb). Anyway Thanks a lot for your effort. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with stuff.
The reason you get the error is this:
`count(*)` returns an int. `char(13)` is a `char`. Whenever you try to do `int + char` SQL Server will try to implicitly convert the `char` to an `int`. Naturally, `char(13)` cannot be converted to an `int`.
What you need to to explicitly convert the `count(*)` to `varchar`:

```
SELECT table2id, stuff(
     (
     select CHAR(13) + cast(count(*) as varchar(10)) 
     from table1 
     where table1id=table2.table2id 
     FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
from table2 
where table2id=117 
group by id;
```

Comment: ThankYou, the above query worked , but it has not served my purpose, I want my result like I have shown you on the top , in my post !!

Comment: I don't think you have another choice then to write the stuff sub query for each column. You can probably shorten the query code by using information_schema.columns to generate the query dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will helps you by using Dynamic Sql
Firstly i created Two physical Tables with sample data

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (table1id INT , table1name Varchar(100) , table1color Varchar(100) , table1city Varchar(100) , table1animal Varchar(100))
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT 117, 'jon' , 'blue'        , 'city1'      , 'animal1' UNION ALL     
SELECT 117, 'jack', 'red'         , 'city2'      , 'animal2'   

CREATE TABLE Table2( table2id INT, table2uniqueid nvarchar(1000))
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT 117,'asbn6383hhh3j3837' Union all
SELECT 118,'kf9s8sujfu6df5d7j'
```

Dynamic Sql code to get the expected result

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMP

CREATE TABLE #TEMP(ID INT IDENTITY ,Query nvarchar(max))

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#TEMP2') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMP2

CREATE TABLE #TEMP2(ID INT IDENTITY ,Query nvarchar(max))

DECLARE @MinID INT,
        @MaxID INT,
        @Sql nvarchar(max),
        @Getcolumn nvarchar(max),
        @Sql2 nvarchar(max),
        @CteSql nvarchar(max),
        @CteSql2 nvarchar(max),
        @FullSql nvarchar(max)

DEClare @COlumn Table 
(
ID INT IDENTITY,
COlumnname varchar(100)
)
INSERT into @COlumn(COlumnname)
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where TABLE_NAME='Table1'

SELECT @MinID=MIn(Id),@MaxID=MAX(ID)FRom @COlumn

While (@MinID <=@MaxID)
Begin

SELECT @Getcolumn=COlumnname From @COlumn WHERE ID=@MinID

SET @Sql=N' STUFF((SELECT  '', ''+ CAST('+@Getcolumn +' AS VARCHAR(5))   
        FROM cte AS i
        WHERE i.table1id=o.table1id For XML PATH ('''')),1,1,'''') AS '+@Getcolumn 

INSERT INTO #TEMP(Query)
SELECT @Sql

SET @MinID=@MinID+1
END


    SELECT DISTINCT @Sql2= 
        STUFF((SELECT ', '+ CAST(Query AS nvarchar(max)) FROM #TEMP i For Xml Path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
        , 1, 2, '')
FROM #TEMP o

SET @Sql2=@Sql2 +' FRom Cte o'

 SET @CteSql= 'SELECT Top 1 '+''' ;With cte
AS
(SELECT  T2.table2id,''+ STUFF((SELECT '', ''+''T1.''+COLUMN_NAME  FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                    Where TABLE_NAME=''Table1'' For XML PATH ('''')),1,1,'''') +'' From   Table2 T2
 LEFT JOIN Table1 T1
 On T1.table1id=t2.table2id )''' +'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'+'''SELECT DISTINCT table2id,''
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where TABLE_NAME=''Table1'''

INSERT INTO #TEMP2(Query)
EXECUTE(@CteSql)
SELECT  @CteSql2= Query From #TEMP2

SET @FullSql=@CteSql2+@Sql2

PRINT @FullSql
EXEC(@FullSql)

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Result After Running the Query

```
table2id    table1id        table1name   table1color    table1city       table1animal
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
117         117, 117        jon, jack    blue, red      city1, city2     anima, anima
118         NULL            NULL         NULL           NULL             NULL
```

Comment: I have 25 columns, for each column I have to do this ?? it becomes very lengthy, also i have to use this logic in left outer join !!! Please advise.